# Can't secure boot Dell Vostro laptop running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, laptop, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 5481 that runs only Ubuntu 18. I'm not able to boot the operating system, the laptop gets stuck on a screen that says
`[FAILED] Failed to start VirtualBox Linux kernel module.`
I looked this up and the most common solution was to turn off secure boot before installing stuff on Ubuntu.

I have tried holding F2, F10, and F12 while booting but it takes me straight to this error screen instead of BIOS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 works with Secure Boot turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the keys ONCE at booting - just as the (DELL) logo appears, holding might not work.

Try esc for "Advanced options" in grub menu.

The virtualbox module needs to be signed (for secure booting) or the booting be done in insecure mode.

Signing / changing boot mode is done by `mokutil` in the shell/terminal (possibly by booting into 'Advanced options >recovery mode') and also in the bios.

I believe the process that needs to be done is described here ->
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS